# Throttling of Electronic Speed Controller with 6S lipo

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, remote-control, speed, controller

Thanks for having look at this.
I had an turnigy 150A ESC and 2000KV bldc motor. I calibrated ESC and it happened perfectly.
I connected 3S lipo to ESC and increased the throttle from 1100uS to 2000uS. Motor reported speed from 2300RPM to 22500RPM respectively.
In aim to increase the speed, I connected 6S lipo to ESC and found a speed of 14000RPM (I expected 4500RPM) for throttle of 1100uS and now the throttle was futher increased to 1200uS, and speed reported was 30000RPM ( I expected as 9000RPM) . I didn't throttle it further.
Can some one please explain why I am getting a huge variation in speed from my expected speed ?
With 3S, my expected speed and actual motor speed were matching.
With 6S, iam getting a 3 times extra speed of my expected speed was obtained.
Thanks for the replies.

Comment: did you recalibrate when you doubled the supply voltage?

Comment: Yes, I did. And heard two beeps, followed by six short beeps, followed by one long beep and one shirt beep. Calibration was perfect. But throttle proportional to speed is not matching with 6s., and matching with 3S. Why was the question?

Comment: When you say "1100uS" which means micro-siemens did you mean "1100 μs" which means microseconds. Capitals matter! Tip: SE supports HTML entities. You can use `&mu;`, all the other Greek letters including `&Omega;` as well as `&deg;`, etc.

Comment: How is the motor loaded?

Comment: @user_1818839. Motor is not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption : No load for all test results

If motor is 2000 KV or 2000 RPM/V then 30kRPM/2000 RPM/V= 15V and divided by 6S = 2.5V /cell ! . Battery ESR is too high compared to motor load resistance for 6S and need 2P6S

but 22500 RPM/2000 RPM/V=11.25V/3S = 3.75V/cell  is OK for 3S

However running at 1100 us where 1000 us is off,  and 2000 us is full power,  indicates you cannot scale performance from the low speed values just above stall speed.

Although 6S @ 10% or 1100 us gave 14000RPM /2000 RPM/V/6= 1.16 V/cell indicates the low range may be off calibration.

It seems your calibration is non-linear. SHow a list of all results from 1000 1200 1400 ... To 2000 us

Comment: Hey Tony, Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I didn't get the context correctly. Can you please elaborate your answer? My question was what made 6s with ESC made the motor to run at more speed than my expected speed? I achieved speed of 41000RPM now with ESC operated at throttle of 1350uS.